How to convert polygon points in a XML file to TFRecord format?
I am currently using a Python script to convert XML files containing object annotations into TFRecord files, which are necessary for training object detection models like Faster R-CNN in TensorFlow. However, the script I’m using is only set up to handle bounding box coordinates (i.e., xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), and it does not account for the conversion of polygon point coordinates that are also present in my XML annotations.
Given that my dataset includes polygons to more accurately represent the shapes of objects, I need to modify the script so that it can correctly convert these polygon annotations into the appropriate TFRecord format.
Question: How can I modify my script to convert the polygon points in my XML files into the TFRecord format, so I can train a Faster R-CNN model with my images? Below is the current script that I’m using, which includes functions for handling the conversion of bounding box coordinates:

def xml_to_csv(path):

    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(label_map)member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height',
                   'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example

How to handle polygon points in the XML files?
How to handle polygon points?

First modify code to read new xml.  Your code is looking for tags : xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax.  What are the tags for the polygon points in new xml?  Each point of the polygon will have an X and Y coordinate.   You will have points[,] which is any array where each point has two values X and Y.  If you have multiple polygons than you have an array of points.

For [mre], please post all import lines, original sample XML, and desired output. And show what current code does. Show us not simply tell us your needs.
